# How to get a local Cloud Foundry Instance?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I’m looking to learn about Cloud Foundry and I’m trying to get a development instance of it set up on my local Windows 10 PC.  But I’m not having any luck.

I’m finding a lot of information about PCF Dev which was deprecated a while ago.  I also looked at the replacement for PCF Dev, CF Dev (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-attic/cfdev).  Its git page mentions that its repository is no longer receiving updates.  I still went ahead and tried installing it using the instructions in the README:

```
cf install-plugin -r CF-Community cfdev
```

But the link it uses to download the plugin is broken:

```
Starting download of plugin binary from repository CF-Community...
Get "https://d3p1cc0zb2wjno.cloudfront.net/cfdev/cfdev-v0.0.18-rc.36-windows.exe": dial tcp: lookup d3p1cc0zb2wjno.cloudfront.net: no such host
```

Can anyone recommend a way to get a development instance of Cloud Foundry set up on my local machine so I can play around with it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find any other solution to this?

Comment: Hi Lyka, I ended up using the instruction here:  https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/cf4k8s-gs/ to install it on a ubuntu linux created under WSL.  Its been working pretty well for me so far to test stuff out.

Comment: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/cloud-foundry-becomes-more-kubernetes-native-with-cf-for-k8s/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, steer clear of pcf-dev and cf-dev, they may still work but are definitely not getting updates so will be way out of date by now.

My understanding, although I haven't tried this process in a while, is that the way to run locally is with VirtualBox. You can run one locally using [bosh-deployment](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-deployment) & [cf-deployment](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/) and Virtualbox.

For instructions installing Bosh in VirtualBox using bosh-deployment, [see the Install Section to install Bosh](https://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite/).

With Bosh installed, [follow the deployment guide to get CF installed](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/main/texts/deployment-guide.md). You can skip to step 4, since you're installing into VirtualBox. Be sure to read the entire document before you begin, however pay specific attention to [this section which has specific instructions for running locally](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/main/texts/deployment-guide.md#for-operators-deploying-cf-to-local-bosh-lite).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I struggled with the VirtualBox install and ultimately went with deploying cloud foundry on a Kubernetes 'cluster' using kind.   I'm on a windows 10 box and used WSL to create a ubuntu instance and followed the direction here to get it up and running: 
 https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/cf4k8s-gs/

Comment: @DavidHarris - That's awesome! thanks for sharing. I'll have to check that out.